# Exibindo dados trimestrais até a data atual POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

Conforme o [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3aa75/1/0), estou exibindo os dados trimestrais de uma tabela, porém, essa consulta está exibindo somente quando tem valor no trimestre (3, 6, 9 ou 12), quando tem valor por exemplo no mês atual (5), não é exibido nada, então...

Como posso ajustar meu código `SQL` para que seja exibido valores trimestrais até a data atual?

*OBS.: Só o último mês que ficaria fora do "padrão" trimestre no caso, para se adequar até o último registro.*

Comment: Tentando entender, você tem uma tabela de `indicadors` que tem instâncias registradas periodicamente na `historico_indicadors`; e agora quer exibir todas as linhas desta tabela que tenham sua `dt_criado` dentro do trimestre corrente, o que quer dizer os meses 1, 2 e 3 para o primeiro trimestre, 4, 5 e 6 para o segundo, 7, 8 e 9 para o terceiro, e 10, 11 e 12 para o quarto, correto?

Comment: Sim. (não havia enxergado seu comentário antes, sorry!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso acontece porque no `where` você estava filtrando exatamente essa situação: somente meses "divisíveis" por 3.

```
AND cast(to_char("HistoricoIndicador"."dt_criado",'mm') as int) % 3 = 0
```

Se entendi bem, você precisa listar os valores dos meses por trimestre, nesse caso você pode usar a função `extract` recuperando o número do trimestre utilizando o interval `quarter`.

```
SELECT 
"IndicadorPeriodo"."id" AS "IndicadorPeriodo__id",
"Meta"."meta" AS "Meta__meta",
(SUM("problemas") / SUM("total")) AS problemas,
extract(quarter from "HistoricoIndicador"."dt_criado") as periodo,
to_char("HistoricoIndicador"."dt_criado", 'yyyy/mm') as mes_ano,
case 
    when extract(month from "HistoricoIndicador"."dt_criado") <= 6 then '1º Sem.'
    else '2º Sem.'
end as semestre
FROM "indicador_funcionarios" AS "IndicadorFuncionario"
    LEFT JOIN "indicadors" AS "Indicador"
        ON ("IndicadorFuncionario"."indicador_id" = "Indicador"."id") 
    LEFT JOIN "historico_indicadors" AS "HistoricoIndicador"
        ON ("HistoricoIndicador"."indicador_id" = "Indicador"."id") 
    LEFT JOIN "indicador_periodos" AS "IndicadorPeriodo"
        ON ("Indicador"."indicador_periodo_id" = "IndicadorPeriodo"."id") 
    LEFT JOIN "indicador_metas" AS "IndicadorMeta"  
        ON ("IndicadorMeta"."indicador_id" = "Indicador"."id")
    LEFT JOIN "metas" AS "Meta" 
        ON ("IndicadorMeta"."meta_id" = "Meta"."id")
WHERE
    "IndicadorFuncionario"."funcionario_id" = 10131 
    AND "IndicadorPeriodo"."id" = 'T' 
    AND "Indicador"."id" = 1
GROUP BY
    "IndicadorPeriodo"."id",
    "Meta"."meta",
    "periodo",
    "mes_ano",
    "semestre"
ORDER BY "periodo";
```

Caso seja necessário exibir uma linha com os totais de cada trimestre, basta remover a coluna `mes_ano` do `select` e do `group by`.

Comment: É exatamente o que eu preciso Camilo, daí no período 1, preciso exibir a soma dos problemas no período 1, no período 2 e assim por diante...
Perfeito, valeu !!

Comment: Cara, uma pergunta! Se eu quiser exibir dados `Semestrais`, como eu poderia fazer? Não encontrei nada na documentação do `EXTRACT`, se puder complementar a resposta, seria interessante, valeu !

Comment: @MarcosHenzel dá pra fazer com o `case`, editei o código SQL com o exemplo.